# show search field when some starts typing on the web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-listener

When someone starts typing (number or alphabets), I want a search bar to appear and it should take the alphabets that are being written by the user in it, ie, I want it to automatically focus on the field.

So far I have this..

```
if (window.addEventListener) {

    var keys = [], listen= /^([0-9]|[a-z])\i$/ ;

    window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){

        keys.push(e.keyCode);

        if(keys.match(listen))
        {
            $('#searchBar').fadeIn();
            $('#searchBar input').text(keys);
            $('#searchBar input').focus();

            keys = [];

        }
    },true);
}
```

I want the first character that was typed in to show in the field too.
Ty.

Comment: What html do you have so far? What is the problem exactly? Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: I just to need to fire of a search field whenever user starts typing on the keyboard. http://jsfiddle.net/mwT49/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works for you. If you prefer jQuery, minor changes needs to be made.

```
<style>
#searchBar { display: none; }
.search { width: 250px; height: 20px; }
</style>
<div id="searchBar">
   Search Here: <input type="search" id="searchInput" class="search" />
</div>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var listen = /^[a-z0-9]+$/i;
    var searchInput = document.getElementById('searchInput');
    var searchBar = document.getElementById('searchBar');

    if ( window.addEventListener )
        window.addEventListener( 'keyup', insertKey, false);

    function insertKey( e ) {
        // Get the character from e.keyCode
        var key = String.fromCharCode( e.keyCode ).toLowerCase(); 

        // Match the character
        if( key.match(listen) ) {

            // Change display: none; to display: block;
            searchBar.style.display = "block";
            // Append every new character
            searchInput.value += key;
            // Focus on input
            searchInput.focus();

            // Since you focused on the input you don't need to listen for keyup anymore.
            window.removeEventListener( 'keyup', insertKey );

            // I didn't tested with jQuery
            // $('#searchBar').fadeIn();
            // $('#searchBar input').append(keys);
            // $('#searchBar input').focus();
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var listen= /^([0-9]|[a-z])\i$/;    
var key = [];
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {

    keys.push(e.keyCode);

    if(keys.match(listen)) {
        $('#searchBar').fadeIn();
        $('#searchBar input').append(keys);
        $('#searchBar input').focus();

        keys = [];
    }

});
```